# Remove folder name from URL using .htaccess, but not admin

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

Wanted to remove directory name `/front/` from the URL using `.htaccess` but not `/admin/`. Below code is working fine and also redirects `/admin/` to `/pages/admin/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)front|shared
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ front/$1 [L]
```

Please suggest to avoid `/admin/` redirection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^front/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(front|shared) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ front/$1 [L]
```